# moving files one after one from one folder to another folder using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have 50 files in a folder and I want to move those 50 files one by one (not together) to another folder. For example after successfully moving the first file to a folder the second file will be moved. Similarly all 50 files should be moved one after one. I want to perform this task in a windows batch script. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,
Pinaki

Comment: to process all files in sequence: `for %%i in (*) do move "%%i" "new path\"`

Comment: And what is your specific question? Please read the help topic [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 0):

use `for` and iterate over every file in the source folder.

```
for %%f in (*) do (
move "%%f" "destination\"
)
```

If you want to scilence the prompting use `/Y`